# Is it tacky to note awards on a conference poster?

Tags: conference

I'm scheduled to present a poster at a conference whose material is from my recently published paper.

The paper has been recognized in a few interesting ways that would be nice to note somehow on the poster. Specifically, *Science Magazine* selected it as Editor's Choice, and the paper has also gotten press coverage in major national outlets. My reason for wanting to list these things is to entice passersby toward the poster.

Would it be tacky to list either or both of these forms of recognition? If not, what would be a good way to do this: perhaps a few icons in the top corner?

Comment: I'll go with yes,  it's tacky.  It seems too immodest.

Comment: "My reason for wanting to list these things is to entice passersby toward the poster." - when I notice something like that, I'll just think: "Ah, this one's an ad. Let's just skip this one and proceed to the next one."

Comment: In addition to the above comments (I agree with both), I would not want to draw much attention to the fact that the work is published. Many people - including myself - prefer to hear about unpublished work at conferences (but this may be field-dependent).

Comment: @Bitwise, I think many fields prefer that conference presentations are on unpublished material and some conferences have policies prohibiting abstract submissions on published work.

Comment: In this case, the paper was accepted and quickly released online after acceptance at the conference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the goal is to have an engaging poster, do you want to engage those who are also researching your topic/field or engage anyone who would be interested in a paper that received accolades, regardless of the topic? The latter does not necessarily result in more exchange in ideas that could further the state of knowledge on your topic, which is what poster presentations are designed to do.

My advice is to design a poster that is engaging through its use of design and content, rather than adding blurbs about its praise. You will engage the right audience, giving you opportunity to talk about the paper with people who might actually read it and use it for their work. A boring poster won't engage a wide audience, even if you include information about it's accolades.